# Why does my code seems to fail and stop at runtime? (C++ file IO)

Tags: c++

I'm currently solving a programming problem to enhance my skills (I'm still a newbie) I've checked my solution line by line and I guess there isn't any problem at all (Or is there?).

[Programming Problem link->](http://ace.delos.com/usacoprob2?a=IPrtvSMhikG&S=gift1)

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nGroup;
    ifstream in("gift1.in");

    in >> nGroup;

    string group[nGroup];


    for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++){
        in >> group[i];
    }


    int money[nGroup];
    for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++) money[i] = 0;
    string tempName;
    int receivers,toGive,tempMoney;

    while(!in.eof()){
      in >> tempName;
      // Give out money
      for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++){   // Check for who gave
          if (tempName.compare(group[i]) == 0){
             in >> tempMoney >> receivers;
             toGive = tempMoney / receivers;
             money[i] -= (toGive * receivers);
          }
      }
      // Receive money
      for (int i = 1; i <= receivers; i++){
          in >> tempName;
          for (int j = 0; j < nGroup; j++){   // Check for who to receive
              if (tempName.compare(group[j]) == 0){
                 money[j] += toGive;
              }
          }
      }

    }

    // Write results to output file
    ofstream fout("gist1.out");
    for (int i = 0; i < nGroup; i++){
        fout << group[i] << " " << money[i] << endl;
    }

    in.close();
    fout.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I tried debugging my code and I'm sure it's working up to the "while(!in.eof()" part.
I intently inserted system("PAUSE"); at the end part just to see if all have gone well, but the problem is that the program just blinks and done. It didn't even created any output file at all.

I'll be very grateful to anyone who can help a newbie like me into this. Thanks! :)

Comment: can you post some sample content for gift1.in?

Comment: @stevieG the sample content can be found on the link above.

Comment: @LihO: Not really :), I just got into this website that has a database of programming problems.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with C?

Comment: @Raven, I'm sure it is, but I can't get to it through my company web filter.. Its usually best to put all the information on the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Gulp.. You cracked my heart but MAN YOU"RE AWESOME! IT TURNS OUT THAT ONE INPUT IS ZERO and that makes my program divide by zero = error... thanks man! I'll learn from this a lot! You can make your comment an answer and I'll check it out to give you the credit you deserve :D

Comment: @Raven: I _am_ pretty awesome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... Haha I won't disagree. I wonder how many years of sleepless coding you had? :D

Comment: @Raven: More than those taken to form the mountains and the sea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`while (!in.eof())` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Where did you learn to do that?

You also have no error handling around your stream extractions. None whatsoever. One of them is used to perform a integer division: what if the division happens with `0`?

- You're likely to see what's confusingly known as a "floating-point exception" (not to be confused with C++ exceptions) come from the OS and terminate your program. That's because you can't integer divide by zero without breaking the universe.

Get yourself into the habit of using a *debugger* to find out what's going on. Stack Overflow is not a debugger.

Comment: @Raven: No problem. A reminder, though, that debugging isn't _really_ what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the *only* problem with your code, but you have made one very common mistake: `eof()` does not become true when you *reach* the end of the file.  It only becomes true when you attempt to read *past* the end of the file.  You need to structure your while loop more like this:

```
for (;;)
{
   in >> tempName;
   if (in.fail()) break; // fail() checks for both EOF and a read error
   // etc
```

A seriously defensive input parser would check `fail()` after *every* `>>` operation; if you can assume some level of correctness in your input you can get away with less than that.

Comment: You can use the more idiomatic `if (!(in >> tempName))` also.  It happens to check for all error conditions, including the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read an entire file and you use `eof` for that; the other answers go into detail why that is wrong, here's how to do it properly:

```
while (in >> temp)
{
    // ...
}
```

This basically means "while you can read from `in` into `temp`, do stuff".